# How to remove duplicates by column (inverse ordering)

Tags: bash, sorting, sed

I've looking for this in here, but did not found the exact case. Sorry if it is duplicated, but I couldn't find it.

I have a huge file in Debian that contains 4 columns separated by "#", with the following format:

```
username#source#date#time
```

For example:

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-07#14:31:40
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-08#09:15:34
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
```

I want to print unique rows based on the first two columns, and if duplicates found, it has to print the last event based on date/time. With the list above, the result should be:

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-08#09:15:34
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
```

I have tested it using two commands:

```
cat file | sort -u -t# -k1,2
cat file | sort -r -u -t# -k1,2
```

But both of them print the following:

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-07#14:31:40 --> Wrong line, it is older than the duplicate one
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
```

Is there any way to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need sort the input file to ensure the order of lines, e.g. for duplicate username#source you will get ordered times. Best is sort reverse, so last event comes first. This can be done with an simple sort, like:

```
sort -r < yourfile
```

This will produce from your input the next:

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-08#09:15:34
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-07#14:31:40
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
```

reverse-ordered lines, where for the each `username#source` combination the latest event comes first.

next, you need somewhat filter the sorted lines, to get only the first event. This can be done, with several tools, like `awk` or `uniq` or `perl` and such,

So, the solution

```
 sort -r <yourfile | uniq -w16
```

or

```
sort -r <yourfile | awk -F# '!seen[$1,$2]++'
```

or

```
sort -r yourfile | perl -F'#' -lanE  'say $_ unless $seen{"$F[0],$F[1]"}++'
```

all the above will print the next

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-08#09:15:34
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
```

Finally you can re-sort the unique lines as you want and needed.

Comment: The second one works very good, but third one, too. This will be used for a very large file, which one has better performance? Thanks :)

Comment: @alesnav have no idea, but you can test the speed yourself ;)

Comment: I'm out of the office, will test it tomorrow :)

Comment: Always use `!seen[$1,$2]++`, not `!seen[$1$2]++`. Consider what would happen in each approach given one line starting with `a#bc` and another with `ab#c`.

Comment: @EdMorton youre absolutely right! Going to edit the answer. Thanx.

Comment: Wont this mess up all the times though, doesn't op want only the latest dates ?

Answer (score 3):

This should work

```
tac file | awk -F# '!a[$1,$2]++' | tac
```

Output

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-08#09:15:34
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
```

Comment: This will work only if events in the input are in ascending order.

Comment: Always use `!seen[$1,$2]++`, not `!seen[$1$2]++`. Consider what would happen in each approach given one line starting with `a#bc` and another with `ab#c`.

Comment: @EdMorton Oh yeah i'll change it now.

Comment: @jm666 That is true, although it appears to be a log in question which will most likely be ordered by date(an assumption) so this should work correctly(hopefully).

Answer (score 2):

```
awk -F\# '{ p = ($1 FS $2 in a ); a[$1 FS $2] = $0 }
          !p { keys[++k] = $1 FS $2 }
          END { for (k = 1; k in keys; ++k) print a[keys[k]] }' file
```

Output:

```
A222222#Windows#2014-08-18#10:47:16
A222222#Juniper#2014-08-08#09:15:34
A111111#Juniper#2014-08-10#14:32:55
A111111#Windows#2014-08-08#10:27:30
```

Comment: It does work, but I don't know if its performance would be OK when treating a 50k rows file... I will test it tomorrow :)

Answer (score 0):

If you know for a fact that the first column is always 7 chars long, and second column also 7 chars long, you can extract unique lines considering only the first 16 characters with:

```
uniq file -w 16
```

Since you want the latter duplicate, you can reverse the data using `tac` prior to `uniq` and then reverse the output again:

```
tac file | uniq -w 16 | tac
```

**Update:** As commented below, `uniq` needs the lines to be sorted. In which case this starts to become contrived, and the `awk` based suggestions are better. Something like this would still work though:

```
sort -s -t"#" -k1,2 file | tac | uniq -w 16 | tac
```

Comment: You're right. That doesn't conform to the question description. I'll delete this answer. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, the column "source" may vary, so this solution is not valid for me.